# Pasting a range with a single cell coverts array of Variant/String to a single String (not an array)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim arr As Variant

Set r = Selection
ReDim arr(1 To r.rows.Count, 1 To r.Columns.Count)
arr = r.Value
```

This code first stores some range as `r`. Then it redimentions `arr` of type `Variant` so that it becomes a 2D array with one 1st order member and one 2nd order member. It looks like this before redimention:

[image]

Then after the redimention it really becomes a 2S array:

[image]

But when I copy values from the range to this array and if the range has a single cell, then array is destroyed and a single `String` is created instead.

[image]

How can I prevent VBA from destroying an array. I want it to stay like it was after the redimentioning.

Comment: Test for the single cell first, then assign to `arr(1, 1)` if there is only one cell.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem. Don't hesitate to put together an answer and get some points.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behaviour

To be on the safe side you can use this function:

```vb
Public Function rangeToArray(rg As Range) As Variant

Dim arr As Variant
If rg.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    arr = rg.Value
Else
    ReDim arr(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
    arr(1, 1) = rg.Value
End If

rangeToArray = arr

End Function
```

As you can see: there is no need to dim arr if there are multiple cells.

Use it like this

```vb
Public Sub test()
Debug.Print "Single cell: " & UBound(rangeToArray(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")), 2)
Debug.Print "Multiple cells: " & UBound(rangeToArray(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C2")), 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `ReDim arr(1, 1)`, you surely meant `ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)`.

Comment: definitly - I updated the answer